# Automating Machine Learning For a List of Data Frames

Tags: python, pandas, forecast, facebook-prophet

Have a list of n data frames with two columns, date and y value. Each df needs to be processed in the machine learning code. The machine learning will produce a set of predictions 1 year ahead. These predictions then need to be added to a file that will house predictions of all the dfs.

The Data Set: [image: This is n df long, and function will need to automate parsing each df into the ml code]

```
'''
model = NeuralProphet(
    growth="linear",  # Determine trend types: 'linear', 'discontinuous', 'off'
    changepoints=None, # list of dates that may include change points (None -> automatic )
    n_changepoints=5,
    changepoints_range=0.8,
    trend_reg=0,
    trend_reg_threshold=False,
    yearly_seasonality="auto",
    weekly_seasonality="auto",
    daily_seasonality="auto",
    seasonality_mode="additive",
    seasonality_reg=0,
    n_forecasts=1,
    n_lags=0,
    num_hidden_layers=10,
    d_hidden=5,     # Dimension of hidden layers of AR-Net
   # Sparcity in the AR coefficients
    learning_rate=None,
    epochs=40,
    loss_func="Huber",
    normalize="auto",  # Type of normalization ('minmax', 'standardize', 'soft', 'off')
    impute_missing=True,
     # Determines the logging level of the logger object
)
```

metrics = model.fit(data, freq="D")
future = model.make_future_dataframe(data, periods=365, n_historic_predictions=len(data))
forecast = model.predict(future)
(forecast[0:])
'''
I need all the predictions in one final df to export for visualization. How can I automate this?

Comment: I would hire a data scientist or ML engineer.  However if you have a specific question about a particular piece of this you can ask and perhaps we can help.

Comment: How can I write a function to automate the parsing of the list into the model for each df.